# Sort Pandas data frame by rows that have multiple similar values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to sort a pandas data frame by rows that have two specific values in any column.  In the sample data below, I would want to select the rows that have a value of 'apple' AND 'grape',

```
  a     b      c
0 apple orange grape
1 grape apple  banana
2 pear  kiwi   apple
```

resulting in a filtered data frame that shows:

```
  a     b      c
0 apple orange grape
1 grape apple  banana
```

Using the the code below, I can select all the rows that have one specific value:

```
df[(df == 'orange').any(axis=1)]
```

The result retuned, as expected, was:

```
  a     b      c
0 apple orange grape
```

Using the following line of code, I expected to select the rows that had both values somewhere in the row, but this returned all the rows that had either apple OR grape as a column value:

```
df[np.isin(df, ['apple', 'grape']).any(axis=1)]
```

I expected to get only the rows that had apple AND grape using the previous line, but that obviously isn't the correct way to accomplish this. How do I go about selecting rows that **only** have **both** values in any column?

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to create a boolean mask:

```
mask=df.isin(['apple','grape']).sum(1).eq(2)
```

Finally:

```
result=df[mask]
```

output of `result`:

```
    a       b       c
0   apple   orange  grape
1   grape   apple   banana
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and with boolean masking try following. Using [`.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) function of Pandas.

```
m1 = (df=='apple').any(1)
m2 = (df=='grape').any(1)
df[m1 & m2]
```

Output will be as follows:

```
    a       b       c
0   apple   orange  grape
1   grape   apple   banana
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to "count" the number of `True`s from np.isin on axis=1 using [sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy-sum) then compare whether it is greater than equal to the number of values that are being checked:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': {0: 'apple', 1: 'grape', 2: 'pear'},
    'b': {0: 'orange', 1: 'apple', 2: 'kiwi'},
    'c': {0: 'grape', 1: 'banana', 2: 'apple'}
})

vals = ['apple', 'grape']

filtered = df[np.isin(df, vals).sum(axis=1) >= len(vals)]

print(filtered)
```

Another option would be to turn the values into a set and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on axis=1 [issubset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
filtered = df[df.apply(set(vals).issubset, axis=1)]
```

Both give:

```
       a       b       c
0  apple  orange   grape
1  grape   apple  banana
```